# Tip of my tongue, a term for how we associate icons and logos with products

Tags: terminology

i remember one of the terms had to do with the icon was actually what it represented. (like illustration of a highway means this is now a highway)

and the other one was something in between like knife and fork reprecenting food

and if i recall correcly the third was something unrelated / abstract doing the reprecenting

(picto..something?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you mean pictogram or pictograph?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pictogram

Comment: I'm glad _you_ understood the question

Comment: this is it! and with that article i found the other, ideogram